# Row-wise IN BETWEEN comparison in a single SQL statement

Tags: sql, postgresql

Given the following tables:

```
CREATE TABLE tree (
    id serial NOT NULL,
    name character varying NOT NULL,
    type integer,
    lft integer NOT NULL,
    rgt integer NOT NULL )

CREATE TABLE item (
    id serial NOT NULL,
    name character varying NOT NULL,
    tree_id integer
    CONSTRAINT fk_tree FOREIGN KEY (tree_id) REFERENCES tree (id) )
```

Columns `lft` and `rgt` on table `tree` are populated using the modified preorder tree traversal (MPTT) algorithm.

Is it possible to get all items attached to tree nodes with type=x and all their descendants all in a **single** query?

Normally, I'd do it in two separate queries like this:

```
SELECT lft, rgt FROM tree WHERE type = x;
/* assume it returns two rows: ((10, 20), (27, 30)) */

SELECT item.id, item.name FROM item JOIN tree ON (tree_id = tree.id)
WHERE ((lft >= 10 AND rgt <= 20) OR (lft >= 27 AND rgt <= 30);
```

The point is that I can only execute a single SQL statement (in a PostgreSQL Database, if it matters). Can you do this with some sort of subquery?

Thanks for any hints.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT  item.*
FROM    tree tm
JOIN    tree tc
ON      tc.lft >= tm.lft
        AND tc.rgt <= tm.rgt
JOIN    item
ON      item.tree_id = tc.id
WHERE   tm.type = x
```

You may want to consider the parent-child model that is much easier to manage.

See these articles in my blog on how to implement it in `PostgreSQL 8.3` and below:

- [**Hierarchical queries in `PostgreSQL`**](http://explainextended.com/2009/05/29/hierarchical-queries-in-postgresql/)

, and in `PostgreSQL 8.4`:

- [**`PostgreSQL 8.4`: preserving order for hierarchical query**](http://explainextended.com/2009/07/17/postgresql-8-4-preserving-order-for-hierarchical-query/)

Comment: item.id and tree.id have nothing to do with the MPTT values stored as lft and rgt. The join from table item on tree can only be done by the foreign key.

Comment: np, thanks for your help. The tree model must be optimized for read performance, thats why the MPTT model was chosen. You're updated answer is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: `@Haes`: note that the way it is now (when you treat `trees` and `items` as distinct entities), it's far from being optimal. Range queries on two distinct columns are very inefficient, even using "bitmap AND's". Is the situation when a tree has **both** child items and subtrees real in your scenario?

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you have problems with writing queries to given data structure, perhaps you should consider using some other data structure? Nested sets (what you showed in here) look cool, but are a major pain when writing queries to them.

Perhaps you could use something like [this](http://www.depesz.com/index.php/2008/04/11/my-take-on-trees-in-sql/) (disclosure: it's a post on my blog).